# SSIS - Programatically Killing active OLEDB Connection

Tags: ssis, oledb

In SSIS I'm interacting with a SQL DB that I only have read access to. The best I can do is use global temp tables.

I want to use a For Each Loop task to cycle through the databases on a server by changing the initial catalog property on the connection. To do this "RetainSameConnection" must be set to false because if it is set to true I can't change the initial catalog (or any part of the connection string) during the For Each Loop.

If I turn "RetainSameConnection" off my problems seem to be solved. The initial catalog changes and a new connection is used for each iteration of the loop. BUT...

The problem is that I need to do 2 SQL steps. Excecute an SQL script, and then Execute a Data FLow that will transfer the contents of a ##TEMP table to another ##TEMP table that exists in another connection where RetainSameConnection is set to true.

I need 2 steps because the query is complex while I have found workarounds by doing some complex things in the SQL query in the Data Query Source they are less than ideal. Of course when I try to use 2 different SQL steps the ##TEMP from the first connection won't transfer over to the Data Flow task because RetainSameConnection is turned off. In a perfect world I could turn RetainSameConnection true during the loop so I could execute multiple SQL tasks and then turn it false at the end of the loop.

This is a long way of asking...

Is there anyway to terminate an active connection (where RetainSameConnection is true) at the end of my loop so I can get the process to create a new session at the beginning of the next loop?

Comment: Sounds exceptionally painful. You'll have the power to kill sessions on the server but not to create a working table? Any chance you have the ability to create a "real" table in tempdb?

Comment: Handwaving magic here, but what if you have two connections to the server. One marked with RetainSameConnection, one not. You can leverage the Application name as part of your OLE Connection string to identify which is which. RSC starts up, does the global temp table thing. You go whackety whack killing processes and then data flow fires or whatever. While I understand the challenges w/r/t temp tables and SSIS, I don't entirely grok why you need to kill connections but that'd be my 4 minutes of thinking about this problem